# Getting typed variable declaration error in a JMeter bean shell script

Tags: jmeter, gson, beanshell

I have this short script in a Bean Shell Post Processor. It uses the GSON library to parse JSON into a Bean. I'm now trying to convert back to JSON using the toJson method but receive this error:

```
Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation gson.toJson
```

Code:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class SavedSearch {
    public String id;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
SavedSearch savedSearch = new SavedSearch();

String newJsonFile = gson.toJson(savedSearch);
vars.put("jobSavedResponse", newJson);
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: After a lot of debugging, I get the feeling the problem lies with the SavedSearch class. I've added in a constructor and getters and setters but get this error: Error invoking bsh method: eval       public class SavedSearch { . . . '' : Method Invocation gson.toJson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got to the bottom of the above issue but found another solution which is probably a better one. In JMeter, I added a BSF PostProcessor instead of a Bean shell script. I chose javascript (the lowercase version) as my language and wrote a short script to perform what I needed to do.

Comment: Hi, yes I got the code to work from my IDE but not from within JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

If there's an exception thrown, then you'll get this error.
Maybe 'savedSearch' had a marshalling error?  Did you try running a unit test with this code?